# VBA to Match Row Height to Pasted Image Size

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a macro that takes a image links in column A of a worksheet, pastes the associated images, and then changes the row height for each row to match the height of the picture in that row.

I got the paste part down but cannot figure out how to set the rowheight. I've tried a dozen different ways but keep getting the "Unable to set the RowHeight property of the Range class" error. Here's the code.

```
Sub ConvertLinktoImage()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim LastCell As String
LastCell = "A" & LastRow

Dim ImageHeight As Long
Dim RowRange As Range
Set RowRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:" & LastCell)

Dim ImageShape As Shape

For Each cell In RowRange
    filenam = cell.Value
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(filenam).Select
    Set ImageShape = Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1)
    ImageHeight = ImageShape.Height
    With ImageShape
        .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        .Cut
    End With

    Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column).PasteSpecial
    cell.RowHeight = ImageHeight
Next cell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try it like this: `Rows(cell.Row).EntireRow.RowHeight = ImageHeight`

Answer (score 3):

This should work

```
cell.EntireRow.RowHeight = ImageHeight
```

instead of

```
cell.RowHeight = ImageHeight
```

> **Explanation why?**
>   You simply can't change the height of a single cell but the height of a entire row.

Comment: Did you try it when `ImageHeight` is > 410 ?

Comment: Absolute maximum row height in Excel is `409.5`. No chance to go above.

Comment: I know, you should mention it in your answer, most of my images are larger

Comment: To avoid it you can resize your image size to max. 409.5 before you adjust the row height, or set the row height to 409.5 if the image size is above.

Comment: Good call. Some of my test images are too big in height. Using the EntireRow switch and adjusting for smaller pictures worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: What units is Excel using? I have one image with a height of 419 pixels native, which results in a .Height value of 314. I have another image whose height is 960 pixels native, which results in a .Height value of 594. Those are different ratios. Since some of my images will be over the max .Height of 409.5, I want to resize them at the same ratio so they can be compared in at least relative size.

Comment: Points: 1 point equals approximately 1/72 inch or 0.035 cm [says Microsoft](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-column-width-and-row-height-72f5e3cc-994d-43e8-ae58-9774a0905f46). 1 pixel  =  0.75 point

Comment: @Peh: Points make sense as a conversion for the 419 pixel image, but the 960 pixel image returns a .Height of 594. That does not equal 960*0.75. That's where I was confused. Other images keep the same ratio of 1 pixel to 0.75 points, but this large one did not. Is there anything else happening here?

Comment: I have no idea, sorry

Comment: possible that it depends on the resolution of the image. And be careful the pixel/point ratio in width is different from height in excel

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, remember that the maximum `RowHeight` is 409.5.

**Note**: I've removed some un-necessary variables, and changed a bit the way you set the `ImageShape`. I would also recommend to change your `ActiveSheet` to fully qualified `Worksheets("YourSheetName")`.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub ConvertLinktoImage()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim ImageHeight As Long
Dim RowRange As Range
Set RowRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & LastRow)

Dim ImageShape As Object
Dim cell As Range
Dim filenam As String

For Each cell In RowRange
    filenam = cell.Value

    Set ImageShape = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(filenam)
    With ImageShape
        If .Height > 409 Then .Height = 409 ' < maximum supported row height is 409.5
        ImageHeight = .Height
        .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        .Cut
    End With

    cell.PasteSpecial
    cell.EntireRow.RowHeight = ImageHeight
Next cell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```